# shareing a data the was returnd in a fetch call to a jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, fetch-api

so I'm building a react and node project

as a part of it, I do a fetch call and I console.log the response

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import Downshift from 'downshift'


export default function TestSearchBar() {
  const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Pokemons();

    async function Pokemons() {
      const res = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:3001/pokemon/names`
      );
      const data = await res.json();
      setPokemonData(data);
    }

  }, []);
  const items = pokemonData;
  return (
    <div>
      <Downshift
        onChange={selection =>
          fetch(`http://localhost:3001/search/${selection.value}`).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
        }
        itemToString={item => (item ? item.value : '')}
      >
        {({
          getInputProps,
          getItemProps,
          getLabelProps,
          getMenuProps,
          isOpen,
          inputValue,
          highlightedIndex,
          selectedItem,
          getRootProps,
        }) => (
          <div>
            <label {...getLabelProps()}>Enter a pokemon </label>
            <div
              style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}
              {...getRootProps({}, { suppressRefError: true })}
            >
              <input {...getInputProps()} />
            </div>
            <ul {...getMenuProps()}>
              {isOpen

                ? items

                  .filter(item => !inputValue || item.value.includes(inputValue))
                  .map((item, index) => (
                    <li
                      {...getItemProps({
                        key: item.value,
                        index,
                        item,
                        style: {
                          backgroundColor:
                            highlightedIndex === index ? 'lightgray' : 'white',
                          fontWeight: selectedItem === item ? 'bold' : 'normal',
                        },
                      })}
                    >
                      {item.value}
                    </li>
                  ))
                : null}
            </ul>

<p></p>


          </div>
        )}
        
      </Downshift>,


    

    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to insert the data that goes into the console into jsx and have it return something like

```js
<div>
pokemon name {data.name}
pokemon stats {data.stats} 
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to share the data I fetched and put it into the console to be put into the jsx
tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the fetch logic into another effect with dependency on a selection value. So when selection will change pokemon will be refetched. Then print to console and update a state of the component. Like this:

```
const [selection, setSelection] = useState();
const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchPokemon = async () => {
     const pokemon = await ...         
     console.log(pokemon);
     setPokemon(pokemon);
  }
  if (selection) {
    fetchPokemon();
  }
}, [selection])

<Downshift onChange={selection => setSelection(selection.value)} ...

{pokemon && <div>
  pokemon name {pokemon.name}
  pokemon stats {pokemon.stats} 
</div>}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is your dependency array in your useEffect is empty, and you are updating state in it. This causes an infinite render loop which could be why you are not seeing anything on the screen.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    Pokemons();

    async function Pokemons() {
      const res = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:3001/pokemon/names`
      );
      const data = await res.json();
      setPokemonData(data);
    }
// Change here: 
  }, [pokemonData]);
```